# Spliting a string in VBA to get a list of numeric values

Tags: vba, split

I would like to split the following string "2/3/4/4" for example and get each number and save them as a list.

I can split the string with the code split("2/3/4/4", "/") but then I cannot manage to put them in a list.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean save them as a list split will return an array. So you can just loop through the array.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "put them on a list"? Maybe you're closer than you think, cause, as said above, you already got it into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, like engineersmnky says you can just return the results of Split() to a String array, like this:

```
Public Sub Test()

Dim results() As String
Dim i As Integer

    results = Split("2/3/4/4", "/")
    For i = LBound(results) To UBound(results)
        MsgBox results(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This would split `"2/3/4/4"` and put the numbers in `A1:A4`

```
Sub SplitAndList()
    Dim nums As Variant, n As Integer

    nums = Split("2/3/4/4", "/")

    For n = 0 To UBound(nums)
        Range("A" & n + 1) = nums(n)
    Next n
End Sub
```